# UICollectionView reloadData weird behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've got storyboard, view with UICollectionView, view controller with outlets. Records are loaded using web service:

```
[[API sharedInstance] getCommentsForArticle:[self.article[@"id"] integerValue] withPage:self.commentsPage onSuccess:^(NSArray *responseData) {
    NSLog(@"LoadCommentsThread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    [self.allCommentsCache addObjectsFromArray:responseData];
    [self.allCommentsCollectionView reloadData];
} onFail:^(NSError *error) {
    DLog(@"Handle error");
}];
```

Number of items is correct on each collectionview request:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Size for item is calculated correctly, even tried constant size for each cell:

```
if (collectionView == self.allCommentsCollectionView) {
    NSString *commentText = self.allCommentsCache[indexPath.row][@"text"];
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300,9999);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [commentText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15.0f]
                                       constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return CGSizeMake(320, 150);
}
```

Problem is with:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

On the initial run, there are 30 elements on the data source array and it's loaded correctly. When there's more loaded, numberofitems returns correct number of items, sizeforitem goes through all of them, but cellforitem goes only for initial 30 items. No matter if there are 100, 200 or more items.

Anyone with similar problem?

Comment: That sounds like the normal behaviour, only the currently visible cells are loaded. The remaining cells should be loaded when you start *scrolling*.

Comment: Ok, solved it by updating collectionview frame ;)

Comment: @blackrain : When you find a solution, please add that here. So it can help someone.